# Rails: how to use fontawesome icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I want to add fontawesome icon

```
<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
```

in place of "Destroy"

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions? http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Comment: you want to display the icon instead of the 'Destroy'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try

```
<%= link_to(
      content_tag(
        :i,
        nil, 
        class: 'fa fa-trash-o'
      ), 
      method: :delete, 
      data: { 
        confirm: 'Are you sure?' 
      } 
    ) 
%>
```

You can try with other things that aren't `:i` like `:div` and if you want text inside like `<i>TEXT</i>` you can try with the TEXT instead of nil, hope this helps you.

Comment: Great suggestion to use `nil` in the `content_tag`. `<i>TEXT</i>` works too but gives italic *TEXT*. I was able to get text plus an icon with `link_to title.html_safe + content_tag(:i, nil, :class => ...)`. If you're using the font-awesome-rails gem, the `fa_icon` helper is another option; see https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use a block like so

```
<%= link_to post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is cleaner IMO.